# Understand basic Impulse Response from Impulse, can you help me visualizing it?

Tags: fft, filters, infinite-impulse-response, impulse-response

I was looking at this graph from *The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to Digital Signal Processing, copyright ©1997-1998 by Steven W. Smith*:

[image]

where basically it shows how differnt representations can contains the same information.

Unfortunately I don't understand how this `Impulse Response` will be created starting from a single `Impulse`:

[image]

I mean: if the `Impulse` is 1 at 0° sample, and 0 for the rest of 127 samples (I guess the window is 128, looking at Sample number of `Impulse Response`), why the "peak" on `Impulse Response` is at 64° sample?

Looking at the `FFT` version, it could be a LP IIR filter? But why it acts exactly in the middle of the windows? Or am I evaluating it in a wrong way and the response is not from a filter?

Comment: The filter has a delay of about $64$ samples, that's why the peak of the impulse response is in the middle of that window. I'd guess it's a linear phase FIR filter. I'm not sure what you mean by "it acts exactly in the middle of the window".

Comment: @MattL. what do you mean with "has a delay of 64 samples"?

Comment: It takes $64$ samples before the main peak of the output occurs. An FIR filter is a tapped delay line. The input signal needs to fill this delay line for the filter to fully combine all past input samples in its memory.

Comment: @MattL. how will look the impulse response of the same filter processed by an IIR filter instead? Is there any tool  can use to test "quickly" these plot?

Comment: @MattL. any tips/suggestions?